# to display data in dropdown depends on other dropdown data

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox, monthcalendar

Hi,
i have one `dropdown` which display year in following format

```
 2012-2013
 2013-2014
```

now i have another `dropdown` which displays month but its depend on financial year,
for eg:suppose if i select year 2013-2014 then i want to display month in `dropdown` in following format

```
April 2013 
march 2013
may 2013
june 2013
july 2013
august 2013
sept 2013
oct 2013
november 2013
december 2013
jan 2014
feb 2014
march 2014
```

this is because we consider year as financial year in which months start from april 2013 and end on march 2014 for year 2013-2014

Comment: In your 2nd dropdownlist is date is shown same except year for every record of 1st dropdown ?

Comment: No i dont want to show date it just month with year

Comment: you can do it by taking two int for year. and bind your 2nd ddl with 1st. post your code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1:**  get the `SelectedItem` from the Year `DropDownList` .
**Step2:**  use `Split()` function to get the year values from the `Selected` String
**Step3:**  Append first year in selected Year to the months DropDownList  from April to December.
**Step4:**  Append Second Selected Year to the months DropDownList from january to March.

Try This:

**Design Code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpYear" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpYear_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>2012-2013</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2013-2014</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drpMonth" runat="server">
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void drpYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String [] Months =new String[] { "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March"};
        drpMonth.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < Months.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i<9)
            drpMonth.Items.Add(Months[i]+" "+drpYear.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('-')[0]);
            else
                drpMonth.Items.Add(Months[i] + " " + drpYear.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('-')[1]);
        }

    }
```